# Why don't people do simulated annealing before gradient descent?

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

It seems obvious to me to first widely explore the optimization landscape (this is effectively what simulated annealing does) and get a sense of the problem structure. Only then, after finding which hill to climb, perform gradient descent. Why isn't this done more often?

Comment: Climbing a hill with a descent algorithm? Simulated Annealing does not tell you 'which hill to climb'.

Comment: @LinAlg SA places numerous seeds on many hills and allows you to descend multiple hills simultaneously, whereas GD descends a single hill. So the question is a good one, why not combine SA w GD -- SA will find which hills to descend while GD descends individual hills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give an example of deep learning, the number of parameters (in Millions) is so huge that simulated annealing may take longer than just doing a gradient descent from whatever (random) initial state your weights are currently in.

So, in case of deep learning it doesn't make (economic) sense to do simulated annealing.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any sources on this?

Comment: [Parameters involved in deep learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network#GPU_implementations) can be found here in terms of 'weights' . You may find it interesting that even though Simulated Annealing is not used, the gradient descent used in deep learning is able to find a global maxima (with high probability) because of high dimension of data.

Comment: To give a piece of similarity between deep learning and simulated annealing is in deep learning [SGD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) is used which introduces the randomness (not by choice but by limilation of RAM memory to do descent on all the training data at once) and a learning rate is used which kind of introduces the 'temperature'. So, its not very different from simulated annealing either.